# AddEventListener not working ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

AddEventListener is being attached only to the last element, can someone let me know why it is happening?

```
listNote(key, value){
    let note = `<div class="mdl-cell--4-col-desktop mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-cell--12-col mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-card mdl-cell sticky-note">
        <div class="message">${value}</div>
        <div class="date">Created on ${this.date}</div>
        <button id=note-${key} class="delete mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-upgraded=",MaterialButton,MaterialRipple">Delete
            <span class="mdl-button__ripple-container">
                <span class="mdl-ripple">
                </span>
            </span>
        </button>
        </div>`
        this.allnotes.innerHTML += note;
        document.querySelector(`#note-${key}`).addEventListener("click", this.deleteNote);
}
```

Comment: firstly, I'd try `id="note-${key}"` (note the quotes) - secondly I'd check the developer tools console for errors .... hmmm, actually, I'd do those the other way around come to think of it

Comment: Why the ecmascript 6 tag? I don't see anything in the code that could not be done with plain old fashioned JS

Comment: Don't program this way, thinking of the DOM as some huge string. Pain will ensue.

Answer (score 1):

When you're *appending* the new note, you're [removing all the children of `allnotes` (those which have event listeners), and then creating them again (without event listeners)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) and then attaching an event listener on the last element only.

Instead, I suggest using [`insertAdjacentHTML(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) if you want to keep the rest of your solution. This way you're not recreating the nodes inside of `this.allnotes`, but just appending the new one. All the old event listeners remain on the old notes!

```
this.allnotes.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', note)
```

[I've made a simple pen to show how this works.](https://codepen.io/kristofferostlund/pen/ybVqOR?editors=1111)